# Changes in weight paint mode not being reflected in pose mode. Why?

Tags: rigging, bones, vertex-groups, pose-mode, weight-paint-mode

I'm new to blender. Currently working on a small project, the idea is to be able to make poses with a character so I can have good references when painting. I downloaded the model, then manually added the rig. I understand I set the armature as parent of the meshes, and the weights were automatically assigned from bones. But when I tried to move the bones in pose mode, there are some fingers that also deform part of the skin of other fingers. Of course I didn't like that. So I investigated a bit and found out you can manually paint the weights of the vertex groups assigned to each bone so you can have more control on what a bone can deform on move.

Problem is... That is not working at all. I paint the weights in whatever way but the changes aren't being reflected when I get into pose mode. Bones keep deforming the mesh in the exact same way no matter what I do, I don't know if I'm missing something.

For instance:

This is the current applied weight for Bone.009.L vertex group.

[image: This is the current applied weight for Bone.009.L (middle finger's first bone) vertex group.]

[image]

This is the result in pose mode:

[image]

Note that it's peeling part of the next finger, even though it's not being painted.

[image]

I can set the weight to 0, erase all, paint in different ways, but that will still happen no matter what I do. Here is how my current hierarchy looks like.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vertices can - and will - be assigned to more than one bone. Check the neighbor groups to check what they are influencing. You can also enable [auto normalize](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/weight_paint/tool_settings/options.html) to make sure weights you paint somewhere are taken from other groups, which will also avoid other issues.

I also highly recommend you to enable your [armature's bone names](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/armatures/properties/display.html) in the properties editor > armature tab > viewport Display, so that you can see them in the viewport and know which vertex groups correspond to which bone.